# Client for a complex system - web or WPF

Tags: asp.net, wpf, architecture

I have a complex legacy system which is essentially a BI tool 
for water management systems. the client of this system is written in winforms,
and it has a fair amount of problems , plus it doesn't look very good.

I am considering writing a new client, and I'm not sure 
If I should choose to implement it in WPF or in web technologies such as ASP.NET MVC.

The client will need to produce reports and graphs,
and allow complex operations for managing the data
(e.g. edit tables , trees etc...)
There will be only dozens of end users for the client.

All this leads to me to WFP , which I'm also more familiar with.
However, there will be some advantages in developing a WEB client,
including ease of deployment, and acceptability for the end user.

So my question is,
in general what are the guidelines for choosing between 
those 2 options? and if possible to tell from my short description,
which of the two is more suited for my needs?

Thanks n advance,
Omer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no general rule of thumb or guideline on how to go about this. Apart from the general desktop vs. web application consideration this decision should be ultimately driven by the requirements which this application should fulfill. And only you and your users could possibly know about these requirements.

Try to do some thinking or research somewhere along these lines:

- Using WPF ties you to the Windows environment. Are you sure there will be no future requirements to support other environments, e.g. various mobile devices? Also since Windows 8 using WPF ties you specifically to the Windows "desktop" environment. What if Metro client would be required?
- Would the web client be just the client side script? If yes, then it needs to be treated and distributed the similar way as the desktop apps. Though this way it could be wrapped up and packaged for multiple client environments similar to native apps. Would this bring some benefits in your case?
- Would the web client need to be hosted on the server? If yes, how would it be hosted? By you, by 3rd party or on-premises by the customers/users? How would you maintain it and provide support in such scenario?

This is roughly what I would think about when making the decision.

Personally, considering current general software trends and Windows platform novelties, I think this is a good opportunity in the lifecycle of the project to leave the native desktop app behind. If I was going for a full client app rewrite and if there was't a solid reason why to go with the desktop solution I would go with the web.

Comment: Thank you. what about the complexity issue? am I correct to assume that building a complex client in the WEB will be more difficult? from what I've experienced so far, things that are easy to do in desktop environments , are far more complicated in web environment. (manipulating trees, tables etc..)Though my lack of experience in the Web environment is a factor in this for sure.

Comment: @omerschleifer The amount of experience with the technology is of course important factor to consider. Especially if no one in the team has required experience. Regarding the complex tasks you mention, there are many vendors of enterprise ready and feature packed web components such as grids, trees or graphs. Check out http://www.telerik.com/ or http://www.devexpress.com/ for good examples of what they have to offer. If, for whatever reason, you would need to develop these complex components in-house, then I agree that this could get to be a difficult undertaking.